# Destroy a dead window in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I know I can kill the current window using C-k, however it doesn't work for a dead window. Is there anyway to kill it? Thank you.

C-a C-k     (kill)        Destroy current window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-wipe`?

Comment: `-windex?` (I did actually search for that option, tragically it does not exist. neither does `-brick`)

Comment: Do you mean: screen -wipe SCREENSESSION ? I want to close the window within a session, not the session.

Comment: @mfinni: What version of screen do you have? I have "4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06".

Comment: I am using Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Comment: @garconcn: Yes, or pid.tty.host, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to call the window in a session. -wipe option works for closing a pid.tty.host.

Comment: @Dennis - I was joking. I couldn't find `-windex` or `-brick` for my `screen`

Comment: @mfinni: C-a C-k doesn't work for me in any case, but C-a k does.